# Dashboard view side by side using python

Tags: python, css

I am new to python and trying to create dashboard and i want the graph to view side by side instead of one below another.

```
app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div(children=[
html.H1('Premium Dash Board'),
html.Div(children='Premium Queue'),
html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(id='example',
                  figure={
                      'data':[
                          {'x': ASIN, 'y': Quan, 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'Quantity'},
                          {'x': ASIN, 'y':List_price, 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'Price'}
                      ],
                      'layout': {
                          'title': 'ASIN vs Inventory & Price'
                      }
                  }),
        ],style={'display': 'inline-block'}),
html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(id='example1',
                  figure={
                      'data': [
                          {'x': ASIN, 'y': Quan, 'type': 'line', 'name': 'Quantity'},
                          {'x': ASIN, 'y': List_price, 'type': 'line', 'name': 'Price'}
                      ],
                      'layout': {
                          'title': 'ASIN vs Inventory & Price'
                      }
                  })

        ], style={'display': 'inline-block'})
],style={'width': '100%', 'display': 'inline-block'})
```

Please advise how to proceed.

Comment: if you use `width: 100%` then `<div>` uses full width of window (browser) and next `<div>` will have to move to next row. For this problem first you have to know HTML and CSS to understand how browser display data.

Comment: I run your code and it displays plots side by side - but I have big monitor. If I resize window to make it smaller then it moves second plot below first plot - it is natural. If I use `'width': '50%'` for every `DIV` then it display side by side even in small window.

Comment: @furas Yes, it is working now. Thank you very much for your help !!

Answer (score 0):

If I run code on big monitor then I see plots side by side.

If I use smaller window then it automatically put second plot below.

But using `'width': '50%'` I can get two plots `side by side`

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc

import random
random.seed(0)

ASIN = list(range(100))
Quan = [random.randint(0, 100) for x in range(100)]
List_price = [random.randint(0, 100) for x in range(100)]

app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div(children=[
html.H1('Premium Dash Board'),
html.Div(children='Premium Queue'),
html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(id='example',
                  figure={
                      'data':[
                          {'x': ASIN, 'y': Quan, 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'Quantity'},
                          {'x': ASIN, 'y': List_price, 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'Price'}
                      ],
                      'layout': {
                          'title': 'ASIN vs Inventory & Price'
                      }
                  }),
        ],style={'width': '50%','display': 'inline-block'}),
html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(id='example1',
                  figure={
                      'data': [
                          {'x': ASIN, 'y': Quan, 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'Quantity'},
                          {'x': ASIN, 'y': List_price, 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'Price'}
                      ],
                      'layout': {
                          'title': 'ASIN vs Inventory & Price'
                      }
                  })
        ],style={'width': '50%','display': 'inline-block'}),
])

app.run_server()
```

TO create this image I used `DevTools` in `Firefox` and function to test page with devices which have different screen size -  `Ctrl+Shift+M`

[image]

[image]